# Recipe for creating a corrupt mysql table

Tags: mysql, testing, mysql-error-1030

We had a process that crashed while trying to manipulate an expected mysql record set, running the offending query from the mysql cli showed the following.

```
mysql> SELECT ...;
ERROR 1030: Got error 127 from table handler
```

Is there a way to easily recreate this condition so we can validate our fix ? (production DB was already repaired).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ perror 127
OS error code 127:  Key has expired
MySQL error code 127: Record file is crashed
```

The cause is most probably a corrupted MyISAM table ... I don't think it's possible to reproduce, unless you actually know how to provoke that corruption :/